# Remove urls, empty lines, and unicode characters in python

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I need to remove url, empty lines and lines with unicode characters from a big text file (500MiB) using python.

This is my file:

```
https://removethis1.com
http://removethis2.com foobar1
http://removethis3.com foobar2
foobar3 http://removethis4.com
www.removethis5.com


foobar4 www.removethis6.com foobar5
foobar6 foobar7
foobar8 www.removethis7.com
```

After the regex it should look like this:

```
foobar1
foobar2
foobar3 
foobar4 foobar5
foobar6 foobar7
foobar8
```

The code I come up is this:

```
    file = open(file_path, encoding="utf8")
    self.rawFile = file.read()
    rep = re.compile(r"""
                        http[s]?://.*?\s 
                        |www.*?\s  
                        |(\n){2,}  
                        """, re.X)
    self.processedFile = rep.sub('', self.rawFile)
```

But the output is incorrect:

```
foobar3 foobar4 foobar5
foobar6 foobar7
foobar8 www.removethis7.com
```

I also need to remove all the lines containing at least one non-ascii char but I can't come up with a regex for this task.

Comment: don't do it all at once, do it line by line

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I tried, but it's extremely slow

Comment: Do you want to change the original file content or create a new file?

Comment: I need to save the output in another file

Comment: What exactly do you mean by Unicode character? Every character even the ASCII ones is contained in Unicode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to encode to ascii to catch non ascii lines which  I presume is what you want:

```
with open("test.txt",encoding="utf-8") as f:
    rep = re.compile(r"""
                        http[s]?://.*?\s
                        |www.*?\s
                        |(\n)
                        """, re.X)
    for line in f:
        m = rep.search(line)
        try:
            if m:
                line = line.replace(m.group(), "")
                line.encode("ascii")
        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            continue
        if line.strip():
            print(line.strip())
```

input:

```
https://removethis1.com
http://removethis2.com foobar1
http://removethis3.com foobar2
foobar3 http://removethis4.com
www.removethis5.com

1234 ā
5678 字
foobar4 www.removethis6.com foobar5
foobar6 foobar7
foobar8 www.removethis7.com
```

Output:

```
foobar1
foobar2
foobar3
foobar4 foobar5
foobar6 foobar7
foobar8
```

Or using a regex to match any non ascii:

```
with open("test.txt",encoding="utf-8") as f:
    rep = re.compile(r"""
                        http[s]?://.*?\s
                        |www.*?\s
                        |(\n)
                        """, re.X)
    non_asc = re.compile(r"[^\x00-\x7F]")
    for line in f:
        non = non_asc.search(line)
        if non:
            continue
        m = rep.search(line)
        if m:
            line = line.replace(m.group(), "")
            if line.strip():
                print(line.strip())
```

Same output as above. You cannot combine the regexes as your are removing lines completely with one if there is any match and just replacing with the other.

Answer (score -1):

this will remove all the links

```
(?:http|www).*?(?=\s|$)
```

explanation

```
(?:            #non capturing group
    http|www   #match "http" OR "www"
)
    .*?        #lazy match anything until...
(
    ?=\s|$     #it is followed by white space or the end of line (positive lookahead)
)
```

Replace white space `\s` with newline `\n` then strip out all empty lines after

Answer (score -1):

Depending on how close to your sample text you want the result to match:

```
( +)?\b(?:http|www)[^\s]*(?(1)|( +)?)|\n{2,}
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/gY7lM2/1)

This magic looks for leading spaces and captures them if present. Then it looks for the `http` or `www` portion, followed by everything not whitespace (I used `[^\s]*` instead of simply `\S*` in case you wanted to add more criteria to exclude). After that, it uses a regex conditional to check whether any whitespace had been collected earlier. If it did NOT, then it tries to capture any trailing whitespace (so you don't remove too much between `foobar4 www.removethis6.com foobar5` for example). Or it looks for 2+ newlines.

If you replace all of that with nothing, it should give you the same output that you were requesting.

Now, this regex is fairly rigid and will likely have many edge cases in which it does not work. This works for the OP, but you may need to provide more details if you need it to be more flexible.